# Unstable beacon entry and exit events

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, estimote

I am developing a android app which can detect beacons.
I have red that beacons can be detected using on entry and on exit functions of the region.

The code is working fine.

But it is continuously sending "onentry" and "onexit" events even though my phone and beacon are not moving.Why is it happening?

I have configured beacon  as region as 
Region=("region1",nul,null,null);

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a beacon not being detected by the Android device for 10 seconds or more.  By default, the library triggers an exit event when it hasn't seen a beacon for this long at the end of a scan cycle.

Several things can cause this:

1. A beacon that is not transmitting frequently enough.  For best results, set your beacon to transmit at 1 Hz or more frequently.  A beacon that transmits once every 5 seconds or less might cause this behavior because not 100% of packets are detected by the mobile device due to radio noise.
2. On some devices (e.g. Nexus 4, Nexus 7, Moto G, Moto X) if WiFi and Bluetooth are enabled simultaneously, WiFi can interfere with the Bluetooth radio.  This can cause intermittent packet losses.  Try disabling WiFi to see if this improves things.
3. The beacon is on the edge of its transmission range.  At the edge of range, only a small percentage of beacon packets are detected.

Comment: I am facing the same issue using alt beacon library. Can you just let me know what can be issue? And its not about all phones but some of devices having this issue.